# How can i add non integer values as hours to a date in R for the length of an input vector

Tags: r

The units are hrs. But i still have the same problem, because it doesn´t add all the values. This is the code i have.

```
initialdates<-function(randomvariable){
  date_0<-"2017-01-01 00:00:00"
  vector_dates<-c(date_0)
  for(i in length(randomvariable)){
    vector_dates<-append(vector_dates,as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00")+sum(randomvariable[1:i]))
  }
  return(vector_dates)
}


initialdates(randomvariablegenerator(100))
```

The output I am getting is the following

```
"2017-01-01 00:00:00 cst"  "2017-01-01 00:03:47 cst"
```

Why I am not getting all of the other elements from the loop

Comment: What is the unit of these values? Years/Days/Hours? If in years, you can use the `date_decimal` function from lubridate: `date_decimal(x+2017)`, where x is your vector.

Comment: What is `randomvariablegnerator`? If it returns 1 value, then you are getting the right number of values out. Without knowing about that function, we can't know how many values *should* be returned, nor can we run your code to test. (Also, careful spelling, `lenght -> length`)

Comment: You also might want to edit your question title. The answer submitted that you say "doesn't solve your problem" is a direct answer to the question in the title.

Comment: randomvariablegenerator is a rbeta function 42*rbeta(n,.123,2.77) and it should generate 100 instances

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date/time to `POSIXct` format and add number (including decimals) to it.

Keep in mind that when your add a number to `POSIXct` then its added as `seconds`.

The problem in above function:

```
initialdates<-function(randomvariable){
  date_0<-"2017-01-01 00:00:00"
  vector_dates<-c(as.POSIXct(date_0))  #Convert to date before adding to vector
  for(i in 1:length(randomvariable)){  #loop should go 1:length(randomvariable)
    vector_dates<-append(vector_dates,as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00")+sum(randomvariable[1:i]))
  }
  return(vector_dates)
}
# Random generated as described in OP
randomvariablegenerator <- function(n){
  return (42*rbeta(n,.123,2.77))
}

# Test type of value function is returning. Test with n = 3 (small value)
ret_val <- initialdates(randomvariablegenerator(3))

#> str(ret_val)
# POSIXct[1:4], format: "2017-01-01 00:00:00" "2017-01-01 00:00:00" "2017-01-01 # 00:00:24" ...
# Returned value is in POSIXct format (date/time)
> as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00") + 100  #100 is converted in 1 min
[1] "2017-01-01 00:01:40 GMT"   #100 is converted in 1 min, 40 seconds

> as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00") + 600
[1] "2017-01-01 00:10:00 GMT"    #600 is converted in 6 min. 

> as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00") + 2 * 60 * 60
[1] "2017-01-01 02:00:00 GMT"     #2 hours has been added

> as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00") + 2.5 * 60 * 60
[1] "2017-01-01 02:30:00 GMT"   #2 hours has been added

#You can even add decimal of seconds(up to millisecond accuracy) i.e
> a <- as.POSIXct("2017-01-01 00:00:00") + 10.6
> a
[1] "2017-01-01 00:00:10 GMT"    #Make a note that 0.6 sec is hidden part

> a <- a + 10.4   #add 10.4
> a
[1] "2017-01-01 00:00:21 GMT"  # 0.6 hidden part is added with 0.4 to make it 21
```

Comment: this doesn´t solve my problem  i am just getting the firs to values that I stated in the output, I don´t understand why the loop is not working. The addition should be performed the number of times the length of the vector

Comment: @aza I have modified your function and added in it my answer. Please look for the comment and you will get the reason. `c(as.POSIXct(date_0)` will ensure your vector is of datetime tyrpe. And perhaps you want your loop to be like `i in 1:length(randomvariable`.

Comment: thank you I already have all of the values. But how can I retrieve all of the values into a  date format

Comment: @aza Gr8. Good that your main problem is solved. All values are alreaady turned in data format. I have added an example in ans.